# Laravel : How to filtered a Collection by Multiple Filters

Tags: php, laravel

I try to filter a collection by multiple filters in an array.
This is what i'm doing, but it doesn't work.

```
$collection->filter(function ($item) use ($filters) {

 foreach ($filters as $filter => $value){
    $buildedFilters = null;
    $buildedFilters .= $item->$filter == $value . "&&";
 }
 return $buildedFilters;
});
```

The way i want to concatenate the filter looks wrong. What could be the best way to do it ?
I don't want to this directly by eloquent to optimise the number of db calls (this is the part of a code in a foreach)

Thanks

Comment: Filter should return boolean. Also your foreach doesn't make sense!

Comment: plz post the `$filters` and the $collection example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a few attribute between each other.
In PHP not empty String equivalent to `true`.
To achieve that you want you will need

```
$collection->filter(function ($item) use ($filters) {

 foreach ($filters as $filter => $value){
   if ($item->$filter != $value) {
      return false;
   }
 }
 return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly event i don't totally understand how. Im gonna study more about this.

Comment: @djoo I guess you are not familiar with functional programming   
I suggest to watch this video in order to understand the magic. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMUiFMZr7vk

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` method should return `boolean`, try this instead:

```php
$collection->filter(function ($item) use ($filters)
{
    $included = true;

    foreach ($filters as $filter => $value){
        $included = $included && ($item->$filter == $value);
    }

    return $included;
});
```